# What is the name/type of the connector on the 28byj-48 stepper motors?

Tags: connector, stepper-motor

These are very useful inexpensive motors however I haven't been able to identify what type of plug is on them to make custom driver boards. Here is a picture: [image: 28byj connectors]

Thanks
Andy

Comment: Looks pretty much like JST: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JST_connector

Comment: I also thought JST but ordered these male connectors: http://www.ebay.co.uk/itm/271527836104?_trksid=p2057872.m2749.l2649&ssPageName=STRK%3AMEBIDX%3AIT which don't fit...

Comment: JST have different families. These are even looking differently on the pic, so I don't know why have you ordered them. The one on ebay is JST-EH. You have something that looks like JST-XH

Comment: Ah, thanks, hadn't appreciated there were variants. Yes, you are correct - checked against my LiPo balance charger which is JST-XH. Post your responses as answer and I'll accept it for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the exact connector of the motor:

- [The PCB part](https://www.conrad.at/de/stiftleiste-standard-xh-jst-800921-rastermass-250-mm-1-st-741229.html)
- [The cable part](https://www.conrad.at/de/buchsengehaeuse-kabel-xh-jst-800187-rastermass-250-mm-1-st-740641.html?sc.ref=Product%20Details) (The picture shows 6 pins but the page says it is the 5 pin connector)
- [The crimp contacts](https://www.conrad.at/de/crimpkontakt-xh-jst-800138-1-st-741112.html?sc.ref=Product%20Details)

In case the links go down, the exact part names are:

- XH JST 800921
- XH JST 800187
- XH JST 800138